# Do I need doctype and other HTML tag in the PHP file that used for AJAX?

Tags: php, ajax, doctype, html

I am using AJAX in my dynamic website. Instead of reloading a whole page, I used AJAX to request PHP file, and change the content of the page.

Is it OK to take away doctype and tags from those PHP files that requested by AJAX?
Will I get any errors in future, if I leave doctype and tags from PHP...

Thank.

Comment: You need to give a lot more information. PHP does not have "doctypes", for one. Post some example code: what do you have, what is going wrong? You mention errors but do not give examples of any.

Comment: Do you mean you've removed the tags from the page that the ajax request is requesting? If you remove it from the page that requests the PHP, then you'll get validation errors

Comment: Sorry, I didn't exlain myself well. I just added some information, I hope it help...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Scenario 1

If the "page" is actually a fragment that is being inserted dynamically into a complete document, you don't need those tags (in fact, they would be invalid).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head></head>
<body>

    <div></div>
    <!-- fine to insert a fragment here -->
</body>
</html>
```

### Scenario 2

If the page needs to stand alone, it must be complete and valid. Even if it displays correctly, it has the potential for major issues.

### Scenario 3

If the PHP page is just serving data (e.g. JSON) in response to an AJAX request, it doesn't need any HTML markup at all (@Sean Dunwoody demonstrates this).

Comment: THANK! Scenario 3 is what I want to know!  and sorry if I gave you a hard time to understand my question :(

Comment: If this answered your question, please mark this answer as the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you have a PHP file and you're making an ajax request to it - say for example getting more information about a user using a get request, e.g.:

http://www.example.com/ajax/userInfo.php?id=4

And your PHP code may look like this:

```
$userId = $_GET['id'];

$currentUser = new user($userId);
$user->printDetails;
```

(I hope this all makes sense)

If that is the case, then no, **you do not need a doctype or `<html><head>` elements in the file.**

I hope I've understood you're question correctly, let me know if not.

Comment: Sorry about my broken English and didn't explain my question good enough :(. But you did understand my question. AND THANK for the answer, that is what I need to know :)